# How to Open a Git Bash Shell inside Box Drive folder

Tags: bash, git, dropbox

I am attempting to open a bash shell inside my Box folder. However, I get the following error: 
"This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.
When I right click and select 'Git Bash Here' in Dropbox, however, the Bash shell opens successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know you can [associate a WSL bash shell to `.sh` files](https://superuser.com/questions/1264874/can-i-drag-and-drop-files-to-an-sh-script-using-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-or-wi) (on Windows 1, with the [WSL feature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) activated)

You could adapt that script in order to not call `"%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\bash.exe"` (the WSL bash) but `C:\path\to\git\bash.exe`

But first, check if the issue persists *outside* a dropbox folder.